# Pass id to Angular by URL parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I do have a list view and a detailed view for single list items. The detailed view is opened by clicking a list entry. This works fine. However, now I want provide links in an email to directly access a detailed item view.

I figured out, I might need **ngRoute** for this, but it does not work as expected. Actually, it does not work at all. My `alert()` function is never called.

This is the relevant part of my controller:

```
var myController = angular.module('myProject.controllers', ['ngRoute']);

myController.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/show/:itemId', {
    templateUrl: 'item-details.html',
    controller: 'MyController'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

myController.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  /** Other stuff... */

  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // $routeParams should be populated here
    alert("itemId: " + $routeParams.itemId);

    if ($routeParams.item) {
      myFunction($routeParams.itemId);
    }
  });

}]);
```

I tried calling my page with both

`http://www.example.com/index.html#/show/123`

and

`http://www.example.com/show/123`

but none worked. Is there anything I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.example.com/#/show/123

Comment: I tried that also, but it does not help. In fact, it will be translated to: http://www.example.com/#%2Fshow%2F123

Comment: The ``routeChangeSuccess`` event never fires. I came across [this blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2770-route-must-be-injected-in-order-to-enable-the-routechangesuccess-event-in-angularjs.htm) and injected ``$route`` before ``$routeParams``, but it still won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in the past I just used a Jquery function

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};


$scope.item = getUrlParameter('show');
```

But you need to change the link to something like:

```
http://dummy.com/?show=123
```

Hope this works, with me it did anyway. Don't know if it is a HAX though.

Comment: JQuery and AngularJS? not sure about this

Comment: Well Angular is based on  the JQuery libary.

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Angular is not a good idea.  If it works for you, great... but I wouldn't recommend it as a solution.

I haven't ever attempted this using the default routing provider, I use ui-router as my provider and I thoroughly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want a solution that by-passes Angular's routing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass arguments to my controller by URL using the [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) dependency:

```
var myController = angular.module('myProject.controllers', []);

myController.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

myController.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  /** Other stuff... */

  /** index.html?itemId=123 */
  var id = $location.search().itemId;

  if (id) {
    alert("Item id: " + id);
    myFunction(id);
  }

}]);
```

This works in terms of parameters being passed to the controller. However, it leaves me with one problem: All `ngClick` buttons in my interface will now also have the query parameter appended, which is kind of annoying, since I do not want to append the `itemId` to a `back` button, for example.

I'll try to figure that one out and will report back, if I find any solution.

This [blog post](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/managing-querystring-angular-location) was helpful in respect to `$location`.